# Not working xpath in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The first xpath is working whereas the second not:

First:

```
"//*[@id='j_idt46:j_username']";
```

Second:

```
"//*[contains(@id,'username']";
```

Why?

Comment: Probably because your missing a closing bracket? Try `"//*[contains(@id,'username')]";`(with a closing bracket after `'username'`).

Comment: what error are you getting? would be good if you can share the html for the same element and what entire code (add language as well) are you using/

Comment: Thanks! Only forgot the closing bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To what could be figured out of the information provided, the way you are using contains is possibly inappropriate :

1. As mentioned by @TuringTux - `//*[contains(@id,'username')]` could be the possible change if the same lined goes as it is in your code.
2. Also a good practice to follow in `//*[contains(@id,'username')]` , would be to replace `*` by an element type in html.
3. And lastly there could be chances when you are trying to access elements using `//*[contains(@id,'username')]`, you may be ending up getting a list of these similar WebElements while you might be trying to access only a single at the same time.